# Reference a vector component

Tags: notation

If I have the following cartesian vector:

$$
\vec{v_1} = \pmatrix{1 \\ 2}
$$

How would I reference the second vector component of: $$ \vec{v_1} $$

Is it okay to do it this way: $$ \vec{{v_1}_y} = 2 $$

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's a widespread notation for this: jsut define it as you like, or say it explicitly.

Comment: My personal choice would be $\pi_2(\vec{v_1})=2$, where $\pi_2\colon K^2\to K$ is the projection on the second component of the vector space $K^2=K\times K$.

Comment: My personal suggestion would be to say that "*If you must work with components, don't use subscripts when naming your vectors*."

Comment: @WillieWong I didn't name the vector (homework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notations I have seen for this:  $(\vec{v_1})_2$, ${\vec{v_1}}_2$, $\pi_2(\vec{v_1})$.  Since you have a subscript already, the second one is a poor choice.  I have not seen $x,y,z$ as subscripts to pick out vector coordinates, but then again I'm a mathematician and in some specialized fields (e.g. engineering) they may actually be very common.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar to Maths software like *Mathematica* or *Maple*, they use the following notation:

> $$v_1[2]$$

Comment: short and sweet! $\color{blue}{\bf +1\;\;\ddot\smile}$

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no problem with double indices. If $v_1 = (1, 2)$ then we might denote the $i$-th component $v_{1i}$ so that we have $v_{11}=1$ and $v_{12}=2$. This is pretty common in some texts about linear algebra when you deal with linear combinations. Indeed, suppose you have $n$ vectors, you can index them like $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ and then the $j$-th component of the $i$-th vector is usually denoted simply $v_{ij}$.

The use of $x,y,z$ as subscripts is common in basic physics textbooks, however in my opinion the notation used in those books is horrible and create dificulties in allowing the reader to forsee possible generalizations. A reader that sees componentes as $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$ is not at first invited to think: "well, why not going to $n$ dimensions?" while a reader that sees $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ is in someway invited to the thought: "well, can't we add more dimensions to that?". Also, numerical indices simplify notations in sums because you can use the summation sign.